# Creating a view which accesses 2 different database which are present on 2 different server

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a view which accesses two different redshift database which is present on two different servers and are independent of each other.
Let's say one contains the data for GA and the other for Facebook.
Now I want to utilise these 2 databases to create a view which accesses these two data. Is it possible to do so using ownership chains?

An alternative I can think of is taking the dump of the data in db 1 into db2 and then utilising it in db2. But it is going to be an expensive procedure.

Comment: No, it is not possible to query across two Amazon Redshift servers from Redshift itself. You _might_ be able to query two Redshift servers from Amazon Athena, but I haven't tried it. See: [Connecting to Data Sources - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/work-with-data-stores.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Any other way you would like to add apart from taking the data dump?

Comment: Another method would be to store one of the datasets in Amazon S3 and access it via [Redshift Spectrum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html), which is like Amazon Athena built into Redshift. It allows joining of data between Redshift and data stored in S3.

Comment: Can you use datasharing for this?  get one of the clusters to share the tables you want, read them from the other cluster.  I'm not sure if this support views.  Note though what you're doing is the very antithesis of Redshift; it's purpose is to provide timely SQL on Big Data, and if you're putting a network in the data reading path, you can't have that, and so I must assume you don't have Big Data, in which case why are you using  Redshift and not, say, Postgres?